# Check email availability in Cakephp using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to check the availability of email through Ajax in Cakephp but it is not working.The form submits normally and adds the duplicate email address in database.Following is the code of template and controller file.

**View.ctp**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").click(function(){
      $("#email").blur(function(){
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/login/users/checkmail",
           data: {email:email},
           success: function(result){
             if(result == 'ok'){
             document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
           }else{
              alert('Email already exists');
            }
         }
       });
       return false;
     });
   });
 });
</script>
<?= $this->Form->create('User',['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],array('id'=>'myForm')) ?>
  <fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('email',array('id'=>'email')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('file',array( 'type' => 'file')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Register')) ?>
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function checkmail(){

if($this->request->is('ajax')){
    $user = $this->request->data['email'];
    $users = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['email'=> $user]);
    $tmp = $users->toArray();
    if(empty($tmp)){
        echo 'ok';
    }else{
        echo '!ok';
    }

}
exit;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Does the Controller always return `ok`? I don't see the the `add` method where you actually store new e-mail address in the database with `save()`. I would in any case change the toArray to `If ($users->count() > 0)`

Comment: Problem is $.ajax is not calling the checkmail function.

Comment: look at this url: "/login/users/checkmail",

Comment: What does the browser debugger give for a http status code? Your controller is called UsersController, but your URL is /login/users/checkmail - do you have some custom routes defined?

Answer (score 0):

**UsersController.php**

```
public function checkmail(){

if($this->request->is('ajax')){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $user = $this->request->data['email'];
    $users = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['email'=> $user]);
    $tmp = $users->toArray();
    if(empty($tmp)){
      echo json_encode(["status"=>"ok"]);
    }else{
      echo json_encode(["status"=>"!ok"]);
    }

  }
  exit;
  }
```

Change your aajx success function

```
success: function(data){
         result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         if(result.status == 'ok'){
         document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
       }else{
          alert('Email already exists');
        }
```

Comment: in success function , above if block add line `console.log(result.status)` and check console of browser @rupinderkaur

Comment: it prints nothing.

Comment: @rupinderkaur remove this condition `if($this->request->is('ajax'))` and try